# Bundler groups in my Gemfile not being honered

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

I have

```
group :production, :staging do
  gem "therubyracer"
end
```

in my `Gemfile`. If I run:

```
bundle install --without production staging test
```

therubyracer is added to my `Gemfile.lock`. Why is this happening please? I would expect it to be ignored?

For completeness, if I remove the line:

```
  gem "therubyracer"
```

and run the above bundle command, then the therubyracer gem is removed from my `Gemfile.lock`

Comment: What is the error you are getting if you simply do "bundle install"

Comment: No error, i just want to be able to selectively install therubyracer

Comment: for that you can simply do "gem install therubyracer" right?

Comment: I could if i wanted to, but i only want it installed on production or staging

Comment: sorry, I have updated my comment

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18681/discussion-between-pingu-and-anandveeramani)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that it's *supposed* to be in `Gemfile.lock`, because `bundle` still needs to calculate and record all of the dependencies and such. However, running `bundle install --without <group>` won't actually *install* the gem - you can check with `gem list -i therubyracer` (although it may have been installed already if you ran `bundle install` without `--without ...`).